# Python key error when using timeit to test dictionary key deletion time

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, timer, timeit

I have become increasingly tired and perplexed trying to get this code to work. This is an algorithm analysis assignment from the "Problem Solving with Data Structures and Algorithms" web textbook. It asks to compare the time it takes to delete a list element and a dictionary element. The test for the list deletion time works fine, but whether I try to delete a dictionary element it gives me a key error. Can anyone explain why this is so?

```
import timeit 
import pylab

x_list = []
delList_list = []
delDictionary_list = []

delDictionary = timeit.Timer("del x[0]",
                      "from __main__ import x")
delList = timeit.Timer("del x[100]",
              "from __main__ import x")
for i in range(10000,100001,20000):

    x_list.append(i)

    x = list(range(i))
    delListTime = delList.timeit(number=1000) 
    delList_list.append(delListTime)

    x = {j:None for j in range(i)}


    delDictTime = delDictionary.timeit(number = 1000) 
    delDictionary_list.append(delDictTime) 


pylab.xlabel('Size')
pylab.ylabel('Time to complete contains operation')
pylab.plot(x_list, delList_list, 'c')
pylab.plot(x_list, delDictionary_list, 'm')
pylab.show()
```

Comment: Could you please attach the error message (stack trace) you are getting?

Comment: `x = {j:None for j in range(i)}` can be replaced by `x = dict.fromkeys(range(i))`, which is *much* faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`timeit` *repeats* the code under test, but your dictionary is not part of that code. As such, after the first delete, you'll get a `KeyError`.

You'd have to generate enough copies of the dictionary up-front, and *in the test code* pick a next dictionary. Do the same for the list objects to keep things on an even keel:

```
delDictionary = timeit.Timer("del next(xiter)[0]",
                      "from __main__ import xiter")
delList = timeit.Timer("del next(xiter)[100]",
              "from __main__ import xiter")

# ... and in the loop

x = [list(range(i)) for _ in range(1000)]  # 1000 identical lists
xiter = iter(x)
delListTime = delList.timeit(number=1000) 
delList_list.append(delListTime)

x = [dict.fromkeys(range(i)) for _ in range(1000)]  # 1000 identical dictionaries
xiter = iter(x)

delDictTime = delDictionary.timeit(number = 1000) 
delDictionary_list.append(delDictTime)
```

So each test is given a *fresh* list or dictionary object, making the comparison fair.

Note that I replaced `{j:None for j in range(i)}` with the far faster `dict.fromkeys(range(i))`; the latter loops in C code, the default value is `None` (but watch out when using `dict.fromkeys()` with a mutable object, no copies are created).